How can i get my Rails 7 mailbox to work?
I have developed a social media site, much like Facebook/Instagram, etc... I am tried to develope a MAILBOX LIKE FACEBOOK. The problem I have is with developing the Mailbox. I do not get the option to send an email!!!!!
I am using Rails 7. a copy by this guy: https://github.com/KhanradCoder/mailbox/blob/master/app/views/messages/index.html.erb
and this guy : https://github.com/danarmulder/simple_rails_messaging_tutorial .
Which are basically the same code. However, I can not get my system to work. I can see the conversation home page, but when I click on the user's email to message the users, I do not get the form to send an email. For some reason it is not reading message.index.html Any thoughts?
Here is the code:
<div class="ui segment">
 <h3>My Mailbox</h3>
 <div class="ui list">
  <div class="item">
   <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
   <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == 
       current_user.id %>
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to recipient.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ui segment">
 <h3>All Users</h3>
  <div class="ui list">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
     <div class="item">
   <%= user.email %> <%= link_to 'Message me!', conversations_path(sender_id: 
    current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method:"post"%>
 </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>

messages/index.html
<% if @over_10 %>
   <%= link_to 'Show Previous', '?m=all' %>
<% end %>

<div class="ui segment">
  <% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <% if message.body %>
      <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="header"><strong><%= user.first_name 
        %></strong> <%= message.message_time %></div>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item">
              <i class="right triangle icon"></i>
              <%= message.body %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= form_for [@conversation, @message], html: {class: "ui 
 reply form"} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
    <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, 
   type: "hidden"  %>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Add Reply", class: "ui blue labeled 
  submit icon button" %>
  </div>

<% end %>


There is no form in your code.

@debugger - there is a message/index.html page that has the form

you can ask repo owners of your examples
